# How to give Minecraft server members permissions for plugin? (server provider: aternos)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to use the waypoints plugin but I need to give me and other members permissions. I was recommended luckperms but since I am doing all this for the first time I was only confused by their explanations. I tried the discord but they only told me to google... is there anyone who can explain it a bit more specifically? I've never done anything like this before ever. Just googling it didn't help, this is why I tried asking people...
the waypoints description says:
waypoints.command:
This permission is required to use the /waypoints command
in case anyone here needs to know that to help me.

Comment: are you opped on the server? i can also see plenty of helpful tutorials online, whats your server running? the answer differs between whats its running.

Comment: all server providers should act the same in regards to the actual game, so its kind of an unnecessary detail

Comment: What does opped mean? And what does "whats your server running" mean? So sorry...

Comment: opped means you can use commands (depending on as set in server.properties). i mean what software is it running, bukkit, forge, sponge, magma, paper ect. You should have to choose it when you setup the server.

Comment: I think it's paper. Also yes, I can use commands. I am the server owner.

Comment: alright just making sure your opped, since its not automatic. alright, make sure your following a tutorial for paper then, as one for say spigot wont always work. i believe it involves editing some files so you will have to open them to change permissions.

Comment: but where do I find the tutorial I need? I tried googling but I am lost...

Comment: search add plugin permissions paper mc. one plugin you can use is luck perms, do pretty much exactly what the tutorial says to do

Comment: yes I installed luckperms and they have a detailed page explaining how it works and I read it but I still don't understand. And when I tried, I think I got something like "that's not a command"

Comment: what command doesnt work?

Comment: "Then, type lp user <your username> permission set luckperms.* true. (don't worry, the usage of this command will be explained later)"